# Firebase and angularFire - getting email from Google authentication works with $authWithOAuthPopup but fails with $authWithOAuthRedirect

Tags: firebase, angularfire

The following code snippet works, unless the user's browser config (iOS with Chrome, e.g.) sends it to the $authWithOAuthRedirect block - then it fails.

And by fails, I mean the $authWithOAuthRedirect method works and the user can approve the authentication, but it fails to send the scope properly to Google, and email access is not requested.

```
var provider = 'google';
var scope = {scope:'email'};
var auth = $firebaseAuth(FirebaseInstance.firebase);

auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(provider, scope).then(function (authData, error) {
    if (error && error.code === "TRANSPORT UNAVAILABLE") {
         auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider, function(error) {}, scope);
    }
});
```

Simplified, this code will fail to request the user's email:

```
var provider = 'google';
var scope = {scope:'email'};
var auth = $firebaseAuth(FirebaseInstance.firebase);
auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider, function(error) {}, scope);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the syntax for the non-angular version:    Firebase.authWithOAuthRedirect(provider[, callback, scope])

You should be using the AngularFire version:
$firebaseAuth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider[, options])

This version returns a promise so your simplified code should look like this:

```
var provider = 'google';
var scope = {scope:'email'};
var auth = $firebaseAuth(FirebaseInstance.firebase);
auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider, scope).then(function (authObject) {
    // Handle success
}, function (error) {
    // Handle error
});
```

Comment: By Jove, that worked.  I read somewhere that we can't expect the promise from the $authWithOAuthRedirect to be delivered, so I was using the callback version.  And that was the problem.  It seems like we can't truly handle authorization in those blocks and instead have to handle `FirebaseInstance.firebase.onAuth(function (authData) {...})` elsewhere.

Comment: "can't truly handle"... no idea what that means. It works fine. But yes, onAuth() is going to be much more useful, since other factors besides your $authWith... call can affect auth status (tokens expiring, logged in on initial page load, et al). So to watch auth status, onAuth() will be appropriate.